# How to deal with PHP-FPM finishing state?

Tags: nginx, php

I have a website using NGINX & PHP-FPM. As you may know PHP-FPM has a status page for it's pools with detailed information about it's processes. **My problem is that as time passes many  processes state become "finishing", and will not change their "finishing" state until I reload PHP-FPM.**

The bad thing is that "finishing" processes counts as active processes and when the number of active processes surpass pm.max_children bad things happen on my website.

I know some php-fpm pool parameters to kill idle processes, but I can't find parameters to kill finishing proccesses after a certain amount of time.

How to deal with PHP-FPM finishing state? Is there a configuration parameter to kill these "finishing" processes after some time? Could this be a misconfiguration between NGINX and PHP-FPM? What are the reasons for "finishing" states?

Here is an image of php-fpm status. Reds are finishing states, which is what I'm trying to fix. Request URI are the different pages of my site.

[image]

Thanks for your knowledge.

**PD1:** Right now I'm reloading PHP-FPM every 15 minutes and that "fixes" more or less finishing states... but I think this could be an important performance problem with more traffic.

**PD2:** Until now the only solution I think could work is to read the php-fpm status page, get all procceses with finishing states and kill proccesses by pid that surpass an arbitrary request duration.

Answer (score 1):

My server had the enablereuse=on setting in the apache proxy configuration.   Removing this fixed the "Finishing" problem.

Also listed in the question: https://serverfault.com/questions/626904/php-fpm-state-finishing-but-never-completes

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Here's what I used as a temporary solution:

Create a PHP file with the content:

```
<?php
fastcgi_finish_request();
?>
```

edit php.ini:

```
auto_append_file = /path/to/your/file.php
```

Comment: Temporary solution? What are you using now?

Answer (score 0):

i had problem like that and this was my fix :

> It turns out we were using invalid Memcached keys in certain
>   situations. This was causing Memcached to die without error and the
>   PHP process was staying alive.

https://serverfault.com/questions/626904/php-fpm-state-finishing-but-never-completes

Answer (score 0):

Neither comment solved or explained the root cause behind the issue. Sample code to perform the PD2 approach in killing these processes of should be something like this:

```
<?php

while (true) {
    $data_json = file_get_contents("http://localhost/fpmstatus?json&full");
    $data = json_decode($data_json, true);

    foreach ($data['processes'] as $proc) {
            if ($proc['state'] === "Finishing") {
                    $pid = $proc['pid'];
                    $duration = $proc['request duration'] / 1000000.0;
                    echo json_encode(compact("pid", "duration"));
                    if ($duration > 60) {
                            passthru("kill -9 " . $pid);
                            echo " KILLED\n";
                    } else {
                            echo "\n";
                    }
            }
    }
    echo count($data['processes']);
    echo "\n";
    sleep(30);
}
```

When running this code, I did find out that errors like this would occur in the error.log:

> 2017/08/06 13:46:42 [error] 20#20: *9161 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 77.88.5.19, server: hostname1, request: "GET /?p=9247 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://uni
>   x:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock:", host: "hostname2"

The obvious mismatch was that the request was handled by the block for "hostname1", and a block for "hostname2" didn't exist (anymore). I can't say for sure that it was the reason. There were "finishing" requests even after declaring a `server_name _;` block, but they were less frequent than anything that was going on before that.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue running nginx + php fpm on Google Cloud Run. I.e. several workers ending up in state Finishing.

After **switching** from Cloud Run first generation to **Cloud Run second generation** the problem was solved.

I found the solution in this issue
[Laravel application hang on Google Cloud Run but runs fine on home setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68951645/laravel-application-hang-on-google-cloud-run-but-runs-fine-on-home-setup)

https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/about-execution-environments