# Laravel application hang on Google Cloud Run but runs fine on home setup

Tags: php, laravel, google-cloud-run

I am testing out Google Cloud Run as a platform to run a new project. Project is developed using NodeJS and Laravel. Created a docker images based on php-fpm. This image runs fine on my dev environment running Ubuntu 21.04 and Docker 20.10.8.
When running the same image deployed on Google Cloud Run the application hangs randomly.
I have narrowed it down to a specific line in imported symfony http send function, class called from laravel index.php. Application will hang a function call to `fast_cgi_finish_request()`. It will hang on that line 70% of cases and call to timeout after 300 seconds when nginx times out.

Hanging line in `./vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Response.php`:

```php
    public function send() {
        $this->sendHeaders();
        $this->sendContent();

        if (\function_exists('fastcgi_finish_request')) {
            /* This line hangs 70% of the time. */
            fastcgi_finish_request();
        } elseif (!\in_array(\PHP_SAPI, ['cli', 'phpdbg'], true)) {
            static::closeOutputBuffers(0, true);
        }
        return $this;
    }
```

Since the same image works on other environments this is specific to Google Cloud Run enviornment. My current guess is some runtime resource since application can respond fine 1-10 times before haning application start to hang.

Any thoughts on how to debug this running in Google Cloud Run platform? I am feeling fairly limited in my debugging options at the moment. Let me know if more details are needed from setup.

Environment passed in to Laravel:

```yaml
  APP_LOG: errorlog
  APP_URL: ...
  APP_ENV: testing
  APP_KEY: ....
  APP_DEBUG: 'true'
  LOG_CHANNEL: 'stderr'
  CACHE_DRIVER: 'database'
  SESSION_DRIVER: 'database'
  DB...
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm as dev
# https://nginx.org/keys/nginx_signing.key
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y curl gnupg2 ca-certificates lsb-release && lsb_release && echo "deb http://nginx.org/packages/mainline/debian $(lsb_release -cs) nginx" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nginx.list && \
    curl -o /tmp/nginx_signing.key https://nginx.org/keys/nginx_signing.key && \
    mv /tmp/nginx_signing.key /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/nginx_signing.asc && \
    apt-get update && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y libpq-dev && \
    docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) pdo_mysql pdo_pgsql && \
    apt-get update && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y nginx

# ----------------------
# Composer install step
# ----------------------
FROM composer:1.10 as build

WORKDIR /app

COPY ./composer.* ./artisan ./
COPY ./database ./database
COPY ./nova-components ./nova-components
COPY ./nova ./nova

## autoload resources
COPY ./bootstrap ./bootstrap
COPY ./app ./app
COPY ./routes ./routes
COPY ./config ./config

RUN composer install \
        --no-dev \
        --no-progress \
        --no-suggest \
        --no-interaction \
        --optimize-autoloader \
        --prefer-dist && \
    composer dump-autoload

# ----------------------
# npm install step
# ----------------------
FROM node:14-alpine as node
WORKDIR /app

COPY ./*.json ./*.mix.js ./artisan /app/
COPY ./resources ./resources
COPY ./public ./public

RUN npm install && \
    npm run build

# ----------------------
# The FPM production container
# ----------------------
FROM dev

WORKDIR /app

COPY ./docker/www.conf /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
COPY ./docker/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY ./docker/entrypoint.sh /
COPY ./docker/php.ini-development ./docker/php.ini-production $PHP_INI_DIR/

COPY ./ /app
COPY --from=build /app/vendor /app/vendor
COPY --from=node /app/public/js/ /app/public/js/
COPY --from=node /app/public/mix-manifest.json /app/public/mix-manifest.json

RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh && \
    rm -f /app/storage/logs/* /app/public/storage && \
    php /app/artisan storage:link && \
    mkdir /var/run/nginx && \
    chmod -R 777 /app/storage /app/app /app/public/app && \
    chown -R www-data:www-data /app/storage /app/app /app/public/app && \
    chown -R www-data:www-data /var/log/nginx /var/cache/nginx /var/run/nginx

USER www-data
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

`composer show`:

```
64robots/nova-fields              0.18.0   A Laravel Nova field.
armincms/nova-tab                 4.0.2    A Laravel Nova tool.
bernhardh/nova-translation-editor 1.3.1    Laravel Nova translation editor
fideloper/proxy                   4.4.1    Set trusted proxies for Laravel
fruitcake/laravel-cors            v2.0.4   Adds CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) headers support in your Laravel application
gkermer/nova-text-auto-complete   0.0.5    A Laravel Nova text autocomplete field.
guzzlehttp/guzzle                 7.3.0    Guzzle is a PHP HTTP client library
intervention/image                2.6.0    Image handling and manipulation library with support for Laravel integration
laravel/framework                 v7.30.4  The Laravel Framework.
laravel/nova                      3.16.3   A wonderful administration interface for Laravel.
laravel/tinker                    v2.6.1   Powerful REPL for the Laravel framework.
listen/nova-flexible-content      dev-main Flexible Content & Repeater Fields for Laravel Nova.
listen/tree-view                  dev-main A Laravel Nova tool.
mcamara/laravel-localization      1.6.1    Easy localization for Laravel
ngiraud/nova-translatable-v2      1.0.4    A laravel-translatable extension for Laravel Nova. Inspired by optimistdigital/nova-translatable
optimistdigital/nova-settings     3.2.1    A Laravel Nova tool for editing custom settings using native Nova fields.
orangehill/iseed                  v3.0.1   Generate a new Laravel database seed file based on data from the existing database table.
silvanite/novatoolpermissions     v1.1.3   Laravel Nova Permissions (Roles and Permission based Access Control (ACL))
waynestate/nova-ckeditor4-field   0.7.0    This nova package allows you to use CKEditor 4 for text areas.
yassi/nova-nested-form            v3.0.12  A Laravel Nova package that allows you to create/update/delete nested related fields from a parent form.
```

nginx.conf:

```
pid /var/run/nginx/nginx.pid;
worker_processes auto;

events {
  worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
  include mime.types;
  #include fastcgi.conf;
  default_type application/octet-stream;
  sendfile on;
  tcp_nopush on;
  server_tokens off;
  client_max_body_size 10M;
  gzip on;
  gzip_disable "msie6";
  gzip_vary on;
  gzip_proxied any;
  gzip_comp_level 6;
  gzip_buffers 16 8k;
  gzip_http_version 1.1;
  gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

  server {
    listen [::]:8080;
    listen 8080 default_server;
    server_name _;
    root /app/public;
    index  index.php index.html index.htm;
    access_log /dev/stdout;
    error_log /dev/stdout info;
    disable_symlinks off;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.html index.htm index.php;
    charset utf-8;

    include includes/*.conf;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ ^/status|^/ping {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        proxy_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
  }
}
```

#### Update

Something is definitly wrong with my setup and executing in cloud run. Enabled `slowlog` and set `request_slowlog_timeout` in php-fpm config. After timeout it releases to nginx and responds correctly. My app is realy slow with this setting but actually works. Missing something in fastcgi/php-fpm setup. Or perhaps Cloud Run is not a good fit for this project.

#### Update 2

After discussion in comments I migrated application to GKE standard where it is running without error since one week.

---

The problem persists even after the removal of secrets per @garbetjje suggestion. I have migrated to using the built in PHP web server. I have been running in Cloud Run for about 1.5 months now without issue. I realise that this is not a long term solution and am currently looking for other runtimes suitable for production use.

#### Update 3

Seems to be something related to first gen of Cloud Run. Deployed app in second generation Cloud Run service now. All functionality have not been thoroughly tested but seems app is working now..

Comment: Cloud Run is just a platform to execute your container. You need to resolve the debugging inside your container. My hint is that you are reaching memory limits declared for the service, and/or long running requests.

Comment: It is very unlikely that Cloud Run or Laravel is the issue. However, there are insufficient details to diagnose what the problem is.

Comment: I agree that Cloud Run is not the problem. The problem is somewhere in the code. But running the image in the Cloud Run environment is causing this bug to appear. A bug that does not show in my dev runtime environment. And code that hangs is part of laravel framework, not the code produced in this project. 

Looking for tips and trix to debug issue in Cloud Run environment. Is there a way to get a stacktrace at a given time? Do laravel provide better debug logs that i have not found ?

Comment: In most headless environments, logging is your friend. The fact that a bug only appears on Cloud Run does not mean much. Bugs are sometimes weird. Make sure your code does not have a timing or race condition. Double-check memory, execution time, etc.

Comment: Updated description. Closing in on error. Narrowed down hanging function call to fastcgi_finish_request(). Most likely there are some config in php-fpm that does not work good in cloud run.

Comment: Tip: do not use `fastcgi_finish_request`. Cloud Run is an HTTP Request/Response system. When the HTTP response is sent to the client, Cloud Run's execution ends. Do not depend on background tasks, threads, locking, etc. Use normal methods to send the response. Finish everything before sending the response to the client.

Comment: @JohnHanley so would say the setup of having nginx --> php-fpm is a bad setup to use in a container environment? Currently NGinx is the process that receives requests from the Cloud Run ingress, which in turn talks CGI to php-fpm. Both Nginx and php-fpm executes as seperate processes in same container.

Comment: The key concept for Cloud run is one request, one response, job done. Cloud Run does support overlapped requests, but they are not the same as a dedicated instance running Nginx. Therefore, complicated/advanced features such as FastCGI do not accomplish anything for your application. Note: I am not commenting on soon to be released features of Cloud Run which makes Run an even better service.

Comment: Can you confirm whether you have any secrets mounted as a volume into your Cloud Run service?

Comment: Yes. I did mount a secret as volume into container under /secrets folder. 
Can also add that the application works fine running on GKE standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have same problem. It's weird that sometimes call small amount line of codes (get data from with eloquent model then send response), i get "upstream timeout".

Now Cloud Run has new different execution environment (beta) https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/about-execution-environments and i'm switching from initial first generation to second generation. Then my application behave normally.

I think the initial first generation have small issues:

- Your service needs to use software that has issues running in first generation due to unimplemented system calls.
- Your service needs Linux cgroup functionality.
  Taken from docs: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/about-execution-environments

Maybe this Github issue is correlated: https://github.com/google/gvisor/issues/158

Comment: Correct! Seems it works alot better if deployed in second generation of Cloud Run. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem recently (specifically, using Laravel Passport).

We were also making use of mounted secrets, and noticed that every 10-30 minutes our application would hang and time out after 60s (our configured timeout in Cloud Run). One of my colleagues noticed that every time our application started hanging, one of the first things to start failing was the reading of the mounted secret.

I [asked about this behaviour in the Google Cloud Community Slack workspace](https://googlecloud-community.slack.com/archives/CHR6C3SCQ/p1631031952027700), and one of the Cloud Run PM's replied indicating that they were rolling back a recent implementation change.

I suspect that you encountered the same issue that we did (running our application in GKE also worked fine).

If it's at all possible, switch to mounting your secrets into your environment. This should resolve the issues of your application hanging.