# Timeout with Laravel App in Google Cloud Run

Tags: php, laravel, docker, nginx, google-cloud-run

I have an issue that already took me hours and I cannot solve it. Maybe somebody of you has a clue what the problem might be, or how I could find out.

### What I'm trying to do

I have a PHP Laravel App packed into a Docker Container to let it run in Google Cloud Run.
The Docker Container utilizes NGINX and PHP-FPM.

### What doesn't work

The Docker Container and app run as expected on my local machine. But in Cloud Run, I get a mysterious timeout. The HTTP request runs for like 300 seconds before the browser gives me a Timeout Error. I cannot see any errors in the app logs in Cloud Run.

This seems to be an application error, not one by Cloud Run or NGINX because if I provoke a different error in my app I will not get a timeout. Instead, I get an HTTP 500 as expected.

### What I already tried

As mentioned the app works fine, when I run the Docker Container with the same image on my local machine. Therefore I have no clue what the error might be.
Sadly the debugging capabilities of PHP in Cloud Run are very limited.
The only idea I had is to sprinkle die() statements in my code at different stages of the execution to see where the timeout occurs.
As you can think this is very time costly because every try I need to rebuild and redeploy.
I gave this a couple of tries but it didn't give me any new insights so far.

Does anybody have a good idea how I could better debug this or even has an idea what the error could be?

Thank you very much!

I know PHP quite well but need to admit that I have limited knowledge about Docker and NGINX.

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM trafex/php-nginx

# install necessary php extensions
USER root
RUN apk add php81-tokenizer

# switch back user to 'nobody'
USER nobody

# copy built app to server dir
COPY --chown=nobody . /var/www/html

# replace default nginx config with custom config
COPY container/prod/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

nginx.conf

```
worker_processes auto;
error_log stderr warn;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    include mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    # Define custom log format to include reponse times
    log_format main_timed '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                          '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                          '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for" '
                          '$request_time $upstream_response_time $pipe $upstream_cache_status';

    access_log /dev/stdout main_timed;
    error_log /dev/stderr notice;

    keepalive_timeout 65;

    # Write temporary files to /tmp so they can be created as a non-privileged user
    client_body_temp_path /tmp/client_temp;
    proxy_temp_path /tmp/proxy_temp_path;
    fastcgi_temp_path /tmp/fastcgi_temp;
    uwsgi_temp_path /tmp/uwsgi_temp;
    scgi_temp_path /tmp/scgi_temp;

    # Default server definition
    server {
        listen [::]:8080 default_server;
        listen 8080 default_server;
        server_name _;

        sendfile off;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        absolute_redirect off;

        root /var/www/html/public;
        index index.php;

        location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to index.php
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
        }

        # Redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root /var/lib/nginx/html;
        }

        # Pass the PHP scripts to PHP-FPM listening on php-fpm.sock
        location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }

        location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|css|js|ico|xml)$ {
            expires 5d;
        }

        # Deny access to . files, for security
        location ~ /\. {
            log_not_found off;
            deny all;
        }

        # Allow fpm ping and status from localhost
        location ~ ^/(fpm-status|fpm-ping)$ {
            access_log off;
            allow 127.0.0.1;
            deny all;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php-fpm.sock;
        }
    }
    
    gzip on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_types text/plain application/xml text/css text/js text/xml application/x-javascript text/javascript application/json application/xml+rss;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    
    # Include other server configs
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

Cloud Run Logs of the mentioned requests:

```
2022-08-13 04:58:56.021 MESZ2022-08-13 02:58:56,021 INFO supervisord started with pid 1
Standard
2022-08-13 04:58:57.046 MESZ2022-08-13 02:58:57,045 INFO spawned: 'nginx' with pid 2
Standard
2022-08-13 04:58:57.077 MESZ2022-08-13 02:58:57,077 INFO spawned: 'php-fpm' with pid 3
Standard
2022-08-13 04:58:57.199 MESZ169.254.1.1 - - [13/Aug/2022:02:58:57 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 497 "https://console.cloud.google.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; CrOS x86_64 14989.10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "103.44.34.133" 0.000 0.000 . -
Standard
2022-08-13 04:58:57.199 MESZ2022/08/13 02:58:57 [crit] 4#4: *5 connect() to unix:/run/php-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 169.254.1.1, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php-fpm.sock:", host: "xxx.run.app", referrer: "https://console.cloud.google.com/"
Fehler
2022-08-13 04:58:57.210 MESZGET5021,19 KB2,6 sChrome 105 https://xxx.run.app/
Standard
2022-08-13 04:58:58.217 MESZ2022-08-13 02:58:58,200 INFO success: nginx entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
Standard
2022-08-13 04:58:58.217 MESZ2022-08-13 02:58:58,217 INFO success: php-fpm entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
Standard
2022-08-13 04:58:59.520 MESZ169.254.1.1 - - [13/Aug/2022:02:58:59 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 497 "https://console.cloud.google.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; CrOS x86_64 14989.10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "103.44.34.133" 0.000 0.000 . -
Standard
2022-08-13 04:58:59.520 MESZ2022/08/13 02:58:59 [crit] 4#4: *7 connect() to unix:/run/php-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 169.254.1.1, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php-fpm.sock:", host: "xxx.run.app", referrer: "https://console.cloud.google.com/"
Fehler
2022-08-13 04:58:59.522 MESZGET5021,13 KB2 msChrome 105 https://xxx.run.app/
Standard
2022-08-13 04:59:00.461 MESZ2022/08/13 02:59:00 [crit] 4#4: *9 connect() to unix:/run/php-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 169.254.1.1, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php-fpm.sock:", host: "xxx.run.app", referrer: "https://console.cloud.google.com/"
Fehler
2022-08-13 04:59:00.464 MESZGET5021,13 KB3 msChrome 105 https://xxx.run.app/
Standard
2022-08-13 04:59:01.248 MESZ169.254.1.1 - - [13/Aug/2022:02:59:01 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 497 "https://console.cloud.google.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; CrOS x86_64 14989.10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "103.44.34.133" 0.000 0.000 . -
Standard
2022-08-13 04:59:01.248 MESZ2022/08/13 02:59:01 [crit] 4#4: *11 connect() to unix:/run/php-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 169.254.1.1, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php-fpm.sock:", host: "xxx.run.app", referrer: "https://console.cloud.google.com/"
Fehler
2022-08-13 04:59:01.250 MESZGET5021,13 KB2 msChrome 105 https://xxx.run.app/
Standard
2022-08-13 04:59:01.331 MESZ[13-Aug-2022 02:59:01] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 3
Standard
2022-08-13 04:59:01.331 MESZ[13-Aug-2022 02:59:01] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
Standard
2022-08-13 04:59:07.001 MESZ2022-08-13 02:59:07,001 INFO supervisord started with pid 1
Standard
2022-08-13 04:59:08.025 MESZ2022-08-13 02:59:08,025 INFO spawned: 'nginx' with pid 2
Standard
2022-08-13 04:59:08.057 MESZ2022-08-13 02:59:08,057 INFO spawned: 'php-fpm' with pid 3
Standard
2022-08-13 04:59:09.059 MESZ2022-08-13 02:59:09,059 INFO success: nginx entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
Standard
2022-08-13 04:59:09.059 MESZ2022-08-13 02:59:09,059 INFO success: php-fpm entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
Standard
2022-08-13 04:59:26.090 MESZ[13-Aug-2022 02:59:26] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 3
2022-08-13 04:59:26.090 MESZ[13-Aug-2022 02:59:26] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
Standard
2022-08-13 05:04:02.071 MESZ169.254.1.1 - - [13/Aug/2022:03:04:02 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 3922 "https://console.cloud.google.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; CrOS x86_64 14989.10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "103.44.34.133" 300.000 300.000 . -
Warnung
2022-08-13 05:04:04.595 MESZTruncated response body. Usually implies that the request timed out or the application exited before the response was finished.
Fehler
2022-08-13 05:04:04.596 MESZGET500721 B301 sChrome 105 https://xxx.run.app/
Standard
2022-08-13 05:04:15.118 MESZ[13-Aug-2022 03:04:15] WARNING: [pool www] child 6 exited on signal 9 (SIGKILL) after 312.945712 seconds from start
Standard
2022-08-13 05:04:16.018 MESZ[13-Aug-2022 03:04:16] NOTICE: [pool www] child 7 started
Standard
2022-08-13 05:04:30.217 MESZ[13-Aug-2022 03:04:29] WARNING: [pool www] child 7 exited on signal 9 (SIGKILL) after 14.100816 seconds from start
Standard
2022-08-13 05:04:31.418 MESZ[13-Aug-2022 03:04:31] NOTICE: [pool www] child 8 started
Standard
2022-08-13 05:04:44.417 MESZ[13-Aug-2022 03:04:44] WARNING: [pool www] child 8 exited on signal 9 (SIGKILL) after 13.111450 seconds from start
Standard
2022-08-13 05:04:45.118 MESZ[13-Aug-2022 03:04:44] NOTICE: [pool www] child 9 started
Standard
2022-08-13 05:04:57.518 MESZ[13-Aug-2022 03:04:57] WARNING: [pool www] child 9 exited on signal 9 (SIGKILL) after 12.699204 seconds from start
Standard

[...]

2022-08-13 05:16:34.417 MESZ[13-Aug-2022 03:16:34] NOTICE: [pool www] child 60 started
Standard
2022-08-13 05:16:48.217 MESZ[13-Aug-2022 03:16:47] WARNING: [pool www] child 60 exited on signal 9 (SIGKILL) after 13.500399 seconds from start
Standard
2022-08-13 05:16:48.818 MESZ[13-Aug-2022 03:16:48] NOTICE: [pool www] child 61 started
Standard
2022-08-13 05:17:00.147 MESZ169.254.1.1 - - [13/Aug/2022:03:17:00 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 3922 "https://console.cloud.google.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; CrOS x86_64 14989.10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "103.44.34.133" 299.999 300.000 . -
Standard
2022-08-13 05:17:01.538 MESZ[13-Aug-2022 03:17:01] WARNING: [pool www] child 61 exited on signal 9 (SIGKILL) after 13.299661 seconds from start
Standard
2022-08-13 05:17:01.818 MESZ[13-Aug-2022 03:17:01] NOTICE: [pool www] child 62 started

2022-08-13 05:17:02.674 MESZ Truncated response body. Usually implies that the request timed out or the application exited before the response was finished.
Fehler
2022-08-13 05:17:02.675 MESZ GET 500 721 B 301 s Chrome 105 https://xxx.run.app/
```

Comment: Post the Cloud Run logs. Also, include nginx.conf.

Comment: I've added the information in the question. I've seen that I now get an HTTP 500 after the timeout. But with no real information about the error. Thanks!

Comment: The logs do not show the container startup or the requests.

Comment: Sorry about that! I added the logs. 
As you can see there is a Notice about a "SIGKILL" 62 times. I did not put in all of these notices as they're all the same to keep it shorter.

Answer (score 1):

After hours of trying and googling, I got a hint here: [Laravel application hang on Google Cloud Run but runs fine on home setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68951645/)

I deployed the container as Second Gen Cloud Run Service, and it works now!

I honestly do not yet understand why this is the case, but it seems to be some incompatibility with Laravel and the First Gen Cloud Run environment.